# Discovered my Jewish heritage at 61 yrs old; now what?

Tags: internet, children-parenting, ashkenazi

For my entire life I believed I was of 100% Italian heritage; typical Neopolitan roots from grandparents who came in the 'big wave' of Italian immigrants in 1900-1910.  I've traveled to Italy and am a member of a geneology group that unites descendants of one tiny mountain town in southern Italy.  OK, so then I send away for the Ancestry DNA kit, and I get my results.
49% European Jewish - Northern (Ashkenazi)
36% Italian, 12% misc other (Caucasus, E. Europe)
After a few seconds of catching my breath, it all became so perfectly clear.  I was the love child of my mother and her boss in the 1950's -- a man she revered and loyally worked for until his sudden death.  I always suspected...now I know.  He was a German Jew.  I know this doesn't technically make me Jewish, but I still want to honor and learn more about this whole new half of my identity.  Suggestions?  Readings?  Online resources?  So many things make sense now....I am very very glad that I finally found this out.

Comment: If you are just looking for random things and ideas about Judaism (you don't say what you current level of knowledge is) try jewfaq.org

Comment: If there is an Orthodox Rabbi near you, call him. He  can usually point you to classes and sources. Chabad representatives often specialize in this type of study and are found in many places that you might not expect.

Comment: you can read To Be A Jew by rabbi Donin.